# Better way to check for equal consecutive elements of size x in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, integer

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 };

        int[] b = { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 };

        System.out.println(consecutiveEqualofSize(a, 5));
        System.out.println(consecutiveEqualofSize(b, 5));
        System.out.println(consecutiveEqualofSize(b, 3));
    }

    public static boolean consecutiveEqualofSize(int[] a, int size) {
        int count = 0;
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (flag) {
                break;
            }
            if (a[i] == 1) {
                for (int j = i; j < i + size; j++) {
                    if (j == a.length - 1)
                        break;
                    if (a[j] == 1) {
                        count++;
                    } else {
                        count = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (count == size)
                        flag = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

The code in the main method print "True, False, True". Im a new student within programming and would like some tips

Comment: It seems you're only interested in consecutive 1s - is that right? Also, do there have to be exactly `x` consecutive elements (terminated by a 0 or the end of the array) are can the consecutive sequence be longer than x? In your examples they're exact.

Comment: Correct only interested in consecutive 1s. Initially, my idea behind the method was to confirm equal consecutive elements of size x in any spot of the array. (If it started in the middle, or near the end). The consecutive elements can be longer than x, I just integrated the int size to demo a boolean method.

Answer (score 0):

Start your loop with the second element. You only need to compare the current element and the previous element to count the duplicates. If you get the desired count return immediately. Something like

```
public static boolean consecutiveEqualofSize(int[] a, int size) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] == a[i - 1]) {
            count++;
            if (count >= size - 1) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code by comparing the current element with the previous one. If they match, increase the counter. If not, return true if the counter matches the passed value, otherwise carry on.

```java
public static boolean consecutiveEqualofSize(int[] a, int size) {
    if (a == null) return false;

    int matched = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] != a[i - 1]) {
            if (matched == size) return true;

            matched = 1;
        } else {
            matched++;
        }
    }
    return matched == size;
}
```